# Get VBA to print an array into excel - array empty

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I have a small program that randomly generates different production rates. I did the program without arrays at first, where the values were printed at every row, which worked and was slow. So now I tried doing the same with arrays and my problem is printing the values:

My code (if you want to test-run it, it should be possible to just copy the code into vba and have one cell in the excel worksheet with the name "Prodthishour"):

```
Sub Production2()

Totalproduction = 10000
Maxprodperhour = 150
Minimumatprod = 50
Timeperiod = 90
Nonprodhours = 10 'Isnt used yet
Openhours = 80
Producedstart = 0 'What we have at the start of the production, often nothing

Prodleft = 10000 'The total production is what is left in the beginning
Dim Produced
Produced = Producedstart

ReDim ProductionArray(Openhours, 1) As Double



For n = 1 To Openhours - 1 'Takes minus 1 value, as the rest will be the last value

    A = Prodleft - Maxprodperhour * (Openhours - n) ' A secures that the randomness isnt such that the production wont be fullfilled

    If A < 0 Then
        A = 0
    End If

    If Prodleft > Maxprodperhour Then
        Maxlimit = Maxprodperhour
    Else
        Maxlimit = Prodleft
    End If

        ProductionArray(n, 1) = A + Minimumatprod + Rnd() * (Maxlimit - Minimumatprod - A)
        Cells.Find("Prodthishour").Offset(n, 1).Value2 = ProductionArray(n, 1)                   

        Produced = Producedstart 'Sets it at the startvalue again to make sure it doesn't accumulate the values
        For Each Item In ProductionArray
            Produced = Produced + Item
        Next


        Prodleft = Totalproduction - Produced

        If Prodleft < 0 Then
            Prodleft = 0
        End If

        If Prodleft < Maxprodperhour Then
            Exit For
        End If

Next n

     Cells.Find("Prodthishour").Offset(1, 0).Resize(UBound(ProductionArray, 1), 1).Value = ProductionArray



End Sub
```

The problem at first was printing the values, but now it seem like the array "ProductionArray" is just printed as zeros.

I find this odd as I use

```
Cells.Find("Prodthishour").Offset(n, 1).Value2 = ProductionArray(n, 1)
```

to test-print the values next to the column that I really want it all to be printed in and also use

```
        For Each Item In ProductionArray
            Produced = Produced + Item
        Next
```

to sum everything, both giving me values, but still ProductionArray is printed as just zeros

(Edited)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the Transpose:

```
 Cells.Find("Prodthishour").Offset(1, 0) _
     .Resize(UBound(ProductionArray, 1),1).Value = ProductionArray
```

(assuming your array has the expected values - I didn't look at that part...)

Comment: Hi Tim! Thank you for clarifying that and I've changed it. Now it, however, doesn't print anything, which, as I now noticed, is because the ProductionArray is empty (I tested by changing the For loop's upper value from "Openhours" to 2,3,4 etc for example).

`ProductionArray(n, 1) = A + Minimumatprod + Rnd() * (Maxlimit - Minimumatprod - A)`

I find it sligthly odd as summing over the ProductionArray apparently gives values that are what they should be.

Comment: Sorry -missed your array declaration `ReDim ProductionArray(Openhours, 1) As Double` is the same as `ReDim ProductionArray(0 to Openhours, 0 to 1) As Double`.  Try `ReDim ProductionArray(1 to Openhours, 1 to 1) As Double` which I think is what you need.

Comment: Thank you very much!!! Now it works! I will put in the correctly working code as an answer tomorrow. =) (No need to apologize in any way for anything when you're helping me out)

Answer (score 0):

I'm now wondering whether I define the matrix correctly using

```
ReDim ProductionArray(Openhours, 1) As Double
```

The odd part for me is that when I use

```
ProductionArray(n, 1) = A + Minimumatprod + Rnd() * (Maxlimit - Minimumatprod - A)
```

The array is printed as zeros, but using

```
Cells.Find("Prodthishour").Offset(n, 1).Value2 = ProductionArray(n, 1)
```

to print the values for each step (as a way to check for errors), gives me perfectly fine values, but these are somehow not present in the ProductionArray when I try to print it at the end.